# Hybrid Shutdown in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

[Referring to this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8) published **September 8, 2011**, it gives instructions on how to to do a full (non-hybrid) shutdown in Windows 8 from the command line.

> We have an option in the UI to revert back to the Windows 7 shutdown/cold boot behavior, or since that’s likely a fairly infrequent thing, you can use the new /full switch on shutdown.exe. From a cmd prompt, run: shutdown /s /full / t 0  to invoke an immediate full shutdown.

```
shutdown /s /full /t 0
```

I tried this in W8 Enterprise RTM trial, but did not work, so I did a

```
shutdown /?
```

and noticed they have changed the command for a Full shutdown

It appears the `/s`  switch now does the full shutdown as explained in the MS article, and the `/hybrid` switch does the hybrid shutdown for fast startup.

Can anyone confirm this change in other RTM versions of Windows 8?

Any Microsoft docs on this change are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

From the help:

```
/hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup.
           Must be used with /s option.
```

Looks like you have to specify both options if you want the hybrid shutdown.

Comment: Just tried this on my Surface (WinRT), shutdown /s /full does nothing where as shutdown /s /hybrid completes the shutdown.