# How to instruct Windows 8 NOT to perform a fast shutdown?

Tags: windows-8

I have enabled fast boot in my copy of Windows 8 but I would like to be able to specifically instruct Windows *not* to perform a "fast shutdown" whenever I want (without disabling fast boot altogether).

I need to be able to do this because I dual-boot Ubuntu and therefore can't mount an NTFS partition as read/write if Windows has performed a "fast shutdown". (Well okay, I can *force* the partition to be mounted read/write, but then I could run into data loss/corruption problems.)

Comment: Check the arguments for shutdown.exe, and also see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/491150/what-does-a-hybrid-boot-do-and-why-wouldnt-i-always-enable-it), [this](http://superuser.com/questions/494861/how-to-add-a-shutdown-tile-windows-8-modern-ui) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/468687/hybrid-shutdown-in-windows-8-rtm) among others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run `shutdown -s -t 0` for a normal shutdown and `shutdown -s -hybrid -t 0` for a hybrid shutdown.

If you always want to do a normal shutdown, follow these steps:

1. Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.
2. Type `change power buttons` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image: S2]
3. Click `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.

   [image: S3]
4. Uncheck `Turn on fast startup`.

   [image: S4]
5. That's it.

Comment: He said he didn't want to turn off fast startup.

Comment: -1. Your answer does not provide any new information that the previous answer and does so in a less concise way. All you added was a copy-paste from [your other answer](http://superuser.com/questions/494965/wake-on-lan-doesnt-work-in-windows-8), which the OP wasn't interested in.

Comment: Your commands in your answer is incorrect. Check it properly.

Answer (score 16):

An easier way then using the command prompt might be the following:

> A full system shutdown is performed by pressing the Shift key at the same time as selecting the shutdown option.

[Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012: Faster Boot Process](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/25/windows-8-windows-server-2012-faster-boot-process.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Use `shutdown /s` for a regular shutdown. Use `shutdown /hybrid` for a fast-boot shutdown.

More information on the [shutdown command](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/shutdown-command.htm).

Comment: Are you sure that /s does a full shutdown even when you have fast startup activated? I don't think that the documentation is perfectly clear. The /s documentation just says "Shutdown the computer", not "Full shutdown" like it says under /r. Also, when I measure shutdown times on my computer with a stopwatch, there is no measurable difference between "/s" and "/s /hybrid".

Answer (score 3):

From the Charms bar:

> Settings -> Power -> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Shut Down

This disables the 'fast start-up' for the next Windows 8 Session.

Semantically, this tells windows Not to write a hibernation file to disk. Having a hibernation file saved on a Windows NT partition will cause partition mouing tools to fail (as to not corrupt the partition by accident.)

Source: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/

Answer (score 2):

**shutdown /s** performs a full shutdown. I am not basing my response on having timed startup (versus **shutdown /s /hybrid**). Rather, I noted that every time I shut down normally, the **PendingFileRenameOperations** registry value is not processed. I just used **shutdown /s** with lots of files to process under **PendingFileRenameOperations**. After having started Windows 8 again, **PendingFileRenameOperations** has been emptied. This means a full shutdown was performed.