# Is there a way to change the default sound volume on startup in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, audio

I've got a Creative X-Fi Titanium running on Windows 8, which works great, but the drivers have this weird quirk where it sets my headphones volume at 30% every time I boot if I have fast boot enabled. If I disable fast boot then it remembers my previous volume but I don't want to disable fast boot any more (I have an SSD, I want to use it :P)

I've asked a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/616231/windows-8-resets-volume-on-shutdown-but-not-on-reboot) before but as you can see the only "solution" was to disable fast boot, which I don't want to do anymore.

Is there a command line tool that will let me set my volume or something similar that I can chuck in a batch file and run on startup, or anything else similar?

Comment: Have you reported this problem to Creative Labs so they can fix this problem?

Comment: Is [NirCMD](http://superuser.com/questions/42039/change-windows-xp-sound-volume-via-the-command-line) or [AutoHotKey](http://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-to-control-master-volume-in-windows-7) a valid solution?

Comment: @nixda I'd like to avoid installing any software, otherwise I'll try just write something in .net to do it for me. I was just wondering if there's something built in to the command line I could use.

Comment: Hm? NirCMD is a command line tool just like you've asked for. No installation needed. And a final AutoHotKey program is a compiled .exe which also doesn't need to install anything. Or short: Both methods don't need any installation

Comment: Ah cool, I didn't realise AHK compiled things, that's pretty awesome. Might give it a shot, thanks :)