# Unable to mount harddrive in LinuxMint on a dual boot config with Windows 8.1

Tags: multi-boot, mount, linux-mint

I have installed linuxmint on a dualboot config with windows 8.1, when I try to browse the files in windows partition (say C:, D:, E:, F:,) it usually shows an error message similar to this one.

but I'm able to browse those partions on rare occations (usually after multiple reboots)

[image: Unable to mount any windows partition]

Answer (score 1):

Your message states "Windows is hibernated. Refuse to mount". This says it all.

Mint has detected that you did not shut down windows. Instead you either hibernated it or used windows fastboot. This means that windows may know the current state of its NTFS volumes.

If you mount those and change the content from Mint, and then return to window there will be a discrepancy between how windows thinks what the disk/volume state is (which is the old state) and with whatever you have changed.

This almost certainly leads to corruption.

Solutions:

1. Fully shut down windows, [link](https://superuser.com/questions/495240/how-to-instruct-windows-8-not-to-perform-a-fast-shutdown)
2. Reformat the partitions and mount the (now empty) volumes.

Comment: I have properlay shutdown windows, But still unable to mount.