# Windows 8 takes too long to shut down

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, hibernate

Windows 8 which I installed recently (from factory recovery image) suddenly now takes too long to shut down, around 2 minutes and 20 seconds.

I tried disabling and enabling "Fast Startup" but that didn't affect the shutdown time.

Also reduced the `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` from 5000ms to 3000ms but also there is no effect.
Also the `ClearPageFileAtShutdown` is set to `0`.

I even tried hibernating instead of shutdown and it took 2:20, too!

Also disabled hibernate with `powercfg -h off` and tried to shut down, and took 2:20, too!

Comment: Have you attempted to remove any external devices( besides keyboard and mouse ) you have installed before you shutdown.

Comment: there was an external hardisk,I removed it but still the same.

Comment: Are you doing an actual power off shutdown or a hybrid shutdown?

Comment: I just pressed Alt+F4 and chose "Shut down" , what is a hybrid shutdown ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/496241/are-there-downsides-to-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown try doing a full shutdown http://superuser.com/questions/468687/hybrid-shutdown-in-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: I did a "shutdown /s /t 0" , same result.

Comment: install the WPT and analyze the shutdown. I posted the commands here: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=158252 . If you're unsure, zip and upload the ETL file (skydrive, dropbox) and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

Holding `Shift` while clicking `Shutdown` will cause the computer to enter a full power off state instead of standby/hibernate. This takes less time than normal shutdown, but your computer will take longer to start up again.

Cheers
Peter